# Is there a way to style react-native components using the useRef hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to change the border color of a TextInput react-native component onFocus. I know I can do it with state but I feel like it would be cleaner if I have a point to the component, and then access the styles of the element and change it.

````
export const LoginScreen = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null);

    const nameInputRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                value={name}
                onFocus={() =>
                    (nameInputRef.current.style.borderColor = 'green')
                }
                onChangeText={setName}
                style={{
                    flex: 0.05,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                    borderWidth: 2,
                    borderStyle: 'solid',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                }}
                ref={nameInputRef}
            />
        </View>
    );
};`
`
```
Expected Behaviour: borderColor of textInput to green when I focus on the textInput

What happened: there is no "style" object in the nameInputRef.current object.

This code works on React for web perfectly but is not working on React-native.
````

Comment: You shouldn't do that even if that's possible. Every change to state will reset styles applied with ref. It's cleaner and better to use state

Comment: @KonradLinkowski okay thank you. Is it possible though?